# How to transpose rows into single column based on time-stamp index in python?

Tags: python, pandas, ipython

**Sample input dataset is:**

> 0  2017-11-17 10:23:28.691     788 756 789 780
>
> 1  2017-11-17 10:23:29.731 788 783 0   0
>
> 2  2017-11-17 10:23:30.655 747 0   0   0
>
> 3  2017-11-17 10:23:31.627 766 0   0   0
>
> 4  2017-11-17 10:23:32.606 807 0   0   0

**Sample output dataset what I want:**

> 0  2017-11-17 10:23:28.691 788
>
> 0  2017-11-17 10:23:28.691 756
>
> 0  2017-11-17 10:23:28.691 789
>
> 0  2017-11-17 10:23:28.691 780
>
> 1  2017-11-17 10:23:29.731 788
>
> 1  2017-11-17 10:23:29.731 783
>
> 2  2017-11-17 10:23:30.655 747
>
> 3  2017-11-17 10:23:31.627 766
>
> 4  2017-11-17 10:23:32.606 807

How can I do this by python or pandas? or is there any other technique to do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [`set_index`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.set_index.html) + [`stack`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.stack.html), then filter out `0` rows and last create `DataFrame` from `Series`:

```
print (df)
                      date    a    b    c    d
0  2017-11-17 10:23:28.691  788  756  789  780
1  2017-11-17 10:23:29.731  788  783    0    0
2  2017-11-17 10:23:30.655  747    0    0    0
3  2017-11-17 10:23:31.627  766    0    0    0
4  2017-11-17 10:23:32.606  807    0    0    0

a = df.set_index('date').stack()
df = a[a != 0].reset_index(drop=True, level=1).reset_index(name='a')
print (df)
                      date    a
0  2017-11-17 10:23:28.691  788
1  2017-11-17 10:23:28.691  756
2  2017-11-17 10:23:28.691  789
3  2017-11-17 10:23:28.691  780
4  2017-11-17 10:23:29.731  788
5  2017-11-17 10:23:29.731  783
6  2017-11-17 10:23:30.655  747
7  2017-11-17 10:23:31.627  766
8  2017-11-17 10:23:32.606  807
```

Answer (score 0):

`replace` + `stack`

```
df.set_index('A').replace({0:np.nan}).stack().reset_index(name='Value').drop('level_1',1)
Out[22]: 
                        A  Value
0  2017-11-1710:23:28.691  788.0
1  2017-11-1710:23:28.691  756.0
2  2017-11-1710:23:28.691  789.0
3  2017-11-1710:23:28.691  780.0
4  2017-11-1710:23:29.731  788.0
5  2017-11-1710:23:29.731  783.0
6  2017-11-1710:23:30.655  747.0
7  2017-11-1710:23:31.627  766.0
8  2017-11-1710:23:32.606  807.0
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use melt

```
df.replace({0: np.nan}).melt(id_vars='datetime', value_vars=['val1', 'val2', 'val3', 'val4']).dropna().drop('variable', axis = 1)

    datetime                    value
0   0 2017-11-17 10:23:28.691   788.0
1   1 2017-11-17 10:23:29.731   788.0
2   2 2017-11-17 10:23:30.655   747.0
3   3 2017-11-17 10:23:31.627   766.0
4   4 2017-11-17 10:23:32.606   807.0
5   0 2017-11-17 10:23:28.691   756.0
6   1 2017-11-17 10:23:29.731   783.0
10  0 2017-11-17 10:23:28.691   789.0
15  0 2017-11-17 10:23:28.691   780.0
```